# Displaying a transparent bitmap in a button with the BS_OWNERDRAW flag

Tags: c++, winapi, button, transparency, alpha-transparency

I have a problem when displaying a transparent bitmap on the button. The new images are simply superimposed on each other, I couldn't find anything sensible on the Internet about this.

Here is the code I have:

```
VOID DrawButton(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT DrawStruct, HBITMAP* BitmapArray)
{
    HBITMAP CurrentBitmap = BitmapArray[BM_UP];

    switch (DrawStruct->itemAction)
    {
    case ODA_SELECT:
        if (DrawStruct->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
        {
            if (DrawStruct->itemState & ODS_FOCUS)
                CurrentBitmap = BitmapArray[BM_DOWN_FOCUS];
            else
                CurrentBitmap = BitmapArray[BM_DOWN];
        }
        break;
    case ODA_DRAWENTIRE:
        if (DrawStruct->itemState & ODS_DISABLED)
            CurrentBitmap = BitmapArray[BM_DISABLE];
        break;
    case ODA_FOCUS:
        if (DrawStruct->itemState & ODS_FOCUS)
            CurrentBitmap = BitmapArray[BM_FOCUS];
        break;
    }
    
    HDC CompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(DrawStruct->hDC);
    HBITMAP hOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(CompatibleDC, CurrentBitmap);
    SelectObject(CompatibleDC, CurrentBitmap);
    AlphaBlend(DrawStruct->hDC, 0, 0, 50, 24, CompatibleDC, 0, 0, 50, 24, { AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 255, AC_SRC_ALPHA });
    SelectObject(DrawStruct->hDC, hOld);
    DeleteDC(CompatibleDC);
    DeleteObject(CurrentBitmap);
}
```

UPD: So, I added the FillRect, but now the image just disappears after I press the button and release it.

```
VOID DrawButton(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT DrawStruct, HBITMAP* BitmapArray)
{
    ...
    FillRect(DrawStruct->hDC, &DrawStruct->rcItem, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(127, 127, 127)));
    HDC CompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(DrawStruct->hDC);
    ...
}
```

[image: Demonstration2]

UPD_2: I finally found some problems, AlphaBlend returns errors after the third call. Error code: 87 (The parameter is incorrect). I don't understand which one? I checked in the debugger - hdcDest, hdcSrc seem to be normal, not NULL, other parameters do not change

[image: Demonstration]
[image: Problem demonstration]

Comment: Once you've drawn something it stays drawn until something erases it or draws over the top.

Comment: You're never selecting `CurrentBitmap` out of `CompatibleDC` before deleting it. That's a bug. You're also deleting `CurrentBitmap` more often than you create it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to invalidate or erase the area as @JonathanPotter said.

There is a Microsoft sample [ChooseFont](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/44d192fd7ec6f2422b7d023891c5f805ada2c811/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/DirectWrite/ChooseFont) which explains this.

```
/******************************************************************
*                                                                 *
* ChooseFontDialog::OnFontSizeSelect                              *
*                                                                 *
* Record the new font size and redraw the sample text.            *
*                                                                 *
******************************************************************/

HRESULT ChooseFontDialog::OnFontSizeSelect()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Signal the sample text window to redraw itself.
    InvalidateRect(GetDlgItem(m_dialog, ID_SAMPLE_BOX), NULL, false);

    return hr;
}
```

Edit:
[InvalidateRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) just issues a `WM_PAINT` message to a window whenever its update region is not empty and there are no other messages in the application queue for that window.

It's erased in `WM_DRAWITEM`.

```
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Fill the DWrite surface with the background color
        HDC dwriteDC = textRenderer->GetDC();
        SetDCBrushColor(dwriteDC, GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE));
        FillRect(dwriteDC, &sampleBounds, GetStockBrush(DC_BRUSH));

        ...
    }
```

Comment: InvalidateRect will just call DrawButton again...

Comment: *"You need to \[...\] erase the area"* - I'm confident there are more promising ways to accomplish this than passing `false` as the `bErase` parameter into the [`InvalidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) call.

Comment: @MyDoomH, I updated my answer. It's the same as the Windows drawing. [*The answer is that Windows asks the window procedure to repaint the window as a two-step process. First, it sends a WM_ERASEBKGND message and then a WM_PAINT message. The default handling for the WM_ERASEBKGND message is to fill the area with the current window background color. So the sequence of events is first to fill the area with solid color and then to draw the text on top*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms969905(v=msdn.10)%20#a-control-that-flickers).

Comment: So, I added the FillRect, but now the image just disappears.
An example is attached in UPD.

Comment: I finally found some problems, AlphaBlend returns errors after the third call. Error code: 87 (The parameter is incorrect). I don't understand which one? I checked in the debugger - hdcDest, hdcSrc seem to be normal, not NULL, other parameters do not change

Comment: It could be [*If the source and destination are the same surface, that is, they are both the screen or the same memory bitmap and the source and destination rectangles overlap, an error occurs and the function returns FALSE*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend). Debug every `DRAWITEMSTRUCT.itemAction` value.

Comment: It turns out that the reason for the error in `AlphaBlend` is that `SelectObject(CompatibleDC, CurrentBitmap)` returns `NULL` with error code 0 (operation completed successfully) after the third call, and again I don't understand why, `CompatibleDC` and `CurrentBitmap` are not `NULL`.

Comment: @MyDoomH In consideration of this details of debugging, could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?